# How can I Delete from a CloudKit container?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cloudkit

Recently I've implemented CloudKit inside my app, I can successfully save the data on CloudKit and show it inside a TableView. The problem is that I can't remove the single data from the container.
Here's the code I use:

```
let database = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
var notes = [CKRecord]()
func saveToCloud(note: String) {
    let newQuote = CKRecord(recordType: "Note")
    newQuote.setValue(note, forKey: "content")
    database.save(newQuote) { (record, error) in
        guard record != nil else { return }
        print("saved record")
    }
}

@objc func queryDatabase() {
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Note", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, _) in
        guard let records = records else { return }
        let sortedRecords = records.sorted(by: { $0.creationDate! > $1.creationDate! })
        self.quotesSavedOnCloud = sortedRecords
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the part of the code that I want to be able to delete data with a swipe:

```
func deleteCloudData(recordName: String) {
    let recordID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: recordName)
    database.delete(withRecordID: recordID) { (id, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {

    deleteCloudData(recordName: String)
    print("Data delated successfully")

    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the code that I'm using right now

Comment: Now that you’ve shown some code, what problem are you having with it?

Comment: When I call the function deleteCloudData(recordName: String) Xcode gave me this error: Cannot convert value of type 'String.Type' to expected argument type 'String'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `String` to `deleteCloudData`, you need to pass a specific string value - the record id for the given index path would be my guess given what you are trying to do.

Get the `CKRecord` for the index path (just like are doing in `cellForRowAt`), and get its `recordID`.

BTW, it would make more sense for your `deleteCloudData` to take a `CKRecord.ID` and not a `String`.

```
func deleteCloudData(recordID: CKRecord.ID) {
    database.delete(withRecordID: recordID) { (id, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        deleteCloudData(recordID: quotesSavedOnCloud[indexPath.row].recordID)
        print("Data delated successfully")
    }
}
```

Comment: For show the data inside the TableView I use: let quoteToDelete = quotesSavedOnCloud[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "content") as! String

Comment: `quotesSavedOnCloud[indexPath.row]` is a `CKRecord`. It has a `recordID` property. That's what you need to pass to `deleteCloudData`.

Comment: And how can I call it?

Comment: It works, but I need to refresh the Tableview in order to make the data disappear